# Way to change only the width of marker in scatterplot but not height?

Tags: python, matplotlib, height, marker, scatter

I want to make a scatterplot with marker type as rectange (not square), such that width is more than height. With the "s" I can control the overall size of the marker but it increases in both dimension.

I can not directly pass height and width as these are unknown properties of scatter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.arange(1,6), np.random.normal(size=5), marker='s', s=16)
```

Comment: `marker="$▬$"` ?

Comment: This works for the shape but does not provide a great control on the ratio of height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
width = 60
height = 30
verts = list(zip([-width,width,width,-width],[-height,-height,height,height]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.arange(1,6), np.random.normal(size=5), marker=(verts,0),s=40)
```

Here, the argument `s` changes the size of the scatter. The drawn rectangle keeps the ratio `width/height`.

**Output:**

[image]

## update

Since matplotlib 3.2x, use of `(verts, 0)` is depreciated. The working code should be changed to

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.arange(1,6), np.random.normal(size=5), marker=verts, s=40)
```

Comment: with matplot3.1 it complains "'<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'"